# Bitmap not setting to ImageView

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I have this intent:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

And then this:

```
getActivity();
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {

         photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
         iPP.setImageBitmap(photo);

    }
```

Now The middle line intent seems to prevent the `imageView` from being set with the `data`.  If I comment it out, the picture I just took with camera sets fine.

I need this line I think so I can write the picture to storage as well. So how can I work around this?

Comment: What do you mean with "The middle line intent"?

Comment: data will be null for that case1, just check if image is stored where you specified...

Comment: @100kg what is best way of getting image path? Ive seen many different thoughts on that.

Comment: you have specified that file > Uri.fromFile(file), so path to your file is in `file`. Then you have to load this `file` int Bitmap or Bitmap scalable

Comment: Ok, figured it out... you can use that as answer..